# HTML - Flask - open a new page on button click without using Javascript

Tags: html, flask

I have a table with a feature to select value of a row to send it to the Flask backend, that on button click also redirects my users to a different endpoint. What I need is to open the new endpoint requested in a **new webpage** instead of the same page. My HTML code where the button is located is as follows. It envelopes a table column value.

```
{% for item in rows %}
<tr>
   <td>{{ item[0] }}</td>
   <td>
      **<button** formaction="/stockpopup" 
         type="submit" name = 'stock' value =  {{`item[11] }}>
      {{ item[11] }}**</button>**
   </td>
   <td>{{ item[1] }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am looking for possible alternates to using JavaScript to achieve this outcome if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `onclick` method inside of html.
Something like this should work:

```html
<button onclick="window.open('https://stackoverflow.com','_blank')">Open in new tab</button>
```

Comment: Hello @sleepystew I tied this. It open the link a new window, however it is opening it as a static page without getting the data it is supposed to get back from server on button click.